# How can I trigger breakpoints when attaching to app using `flutter attach` command?

Tags: ios, flutter

#### What am I doing?

I have a native iOS app, I wrote a Flutter module for a new feature and integrated it into the current native app. In order to use cool Flutter features like `Hot Reload`, I launched the native app in an iOS Simulator, then I open my Flutter project folder in my `VSCode` and ran `flutter attach` to attach the Flutter debugger to the native app, as I opened the `Flutter made` screen, then it was connected, and whenever I make a change in Flutter code, I can hit `r` to trigger a hot reload to see the update on the screen.

#### What is the problem?

I wanted to debug some code so I put some breakpoints, then I triggered a hot reload to run the code which refreshes the UI, the UI was refreshed but...none of my breakpoints was triggered.

#### Question:

Why hadn't these breakpoints been triggered?
If I can not use breakpoints, how can I debug something like this under this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: same problem for me, anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `flutter attach` by VSCode command Palette `VSCode -> View -> Command Palette(Shift + cmd + P)`, search `Debug: Attach to Flutter on Device`, and run this command. If succeeds, then you can trigger breakpoints.